# how to "migrate" from cortexM3 to cortexM4

Tags: c, arm, freertos, openocd

I have an old project, that run on SAM3S( cortex-m3) , I need to use it as a base for a ew project that should run on Sam4S cortex-M4 . After changing the o`opeocd.cfg`  I get this errors, and I don'T get what do they really mean :

```
Error: Target not examined yet
in procedure 'halt'

Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all zeroes
Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: at91sam3s4.cpu: IR capture error; saw 0x00 not 0x01
Error: Target not examined yet
```

can anybody here give a hint where I should look ?

**Update**

now I get this error :

```
Error: SAM4 ChipID 0x28ab07e0 not found in table (perhaps you can ID this chip?)
         Version:     0 [0x0000] 
           EPROC:     7 [0x0007] cortex-m4
         NVPSIZE:     7 [0x0007] 128K bytes
        NVPSIZE2:     0 [0x0000] none
        SRAMSIZE:    11 [0x000b] 64K Bytes
            ARCH:   138 [0x008a] ATSAM3S/SAM4S xC Series (100-pin version)
          NVPTYP:     2 [0x0002] embedded flash memory
           EXTID:     0 [0x0000] (exists: NO)
Error: auto_probe fail
```

any idea what'S the problem now

ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error: at91sam3s4.cpu: IR capture error; saw 0x00 not 0x01
```

You would need architecture and BSP files for cortex-M4. Then you can merge your existing project to the BSP of cortex M4.

`at91sam3s4.cpu` seems like it belongs to cortex M3. So, it will not be there.

However, You would get more answers on atmel website
http://www.atmel.com/tools/SAM4S-EK.aspx

Comment: 1. thanks for your help, aren't the BSP files saved in at91sam4sXX.cfg  file used by openOCD ?

Comment: I hope the SAM4S-EK Demo Sources, download link available on the link mentioned in above answer should be the BSP files you need.

Comment: Can you please describe what exactly you have done from initial to get this updated error.

Comment: it apears that OpenOCD  isn'T not supporting this uC I switch to JLink and now it'S working  thanks for your help